# "Name of function is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

A complete newbie's question:
The code is intended to find the longest string in a list and display it.
It does not work when I run it (as a file, or directly in the shell). I keep getting an error message that the function's name is not recognized. Your help and advice would be highly appreciated.

The correct result is shown with the print command, but when I try to run the complete file I keep getting the above-mentioned error.

```
def longest(mylist):
    mylist = ["111", "44", "baking", "dot"]
list1 = max(["111", "44", "baking", "dot"], key=len)
longest(list1);
print(list1)

Error running the file:
File "<stdin>", line 1
    python [filename].py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Error when pasting the code into the shell:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> mylist = ["111", "44", "baking", "dot"]
>>> list1 = max(["111", "44", "baking", "dot"], key=len)
>>> longest(list1);
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'longest' is not defined
>>> print(list1)
baking
```

Comment: In the shell you seem to have omitted the line where you define the function.

Comment: You don't need a `longest` function separately - just `len(list1)` will do

Comment: Do you try to run `python [filename].py` from the Python shell? You have to use the shell of your OS.

Comment: @Mortz: `len(list1)` will do different things. But the function `longest` does nothing at the moment, that's true.

Comment: @Matthias - yes, misread the question as getting the length of longest string...

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful answers and suggestions. It seems I am more clueless than I thought.  It's obvious that I need more info before bothering you again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not do anything in your code.
Could have shorten to the below.

```
max_value = max(["111", "44", "baking", "dot"], key=len)
print(max_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not written properly, you should go through python tutorials to learn the basics. There are plenty of tutorials available on internet.

[Python Tutorial at TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm)

[Python Official Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)

Now, the answer to your question is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# This is the function which takes list as an argument and
# returns the longest string from the list
def longest(mylist) :
    l = max(mylist, key=len)
    return l

# This is the list which contains all the strings
mylist = ["111", "44", "baking", "dot"]

# This is the function call with "mylist" as argument
# and, the return value is assigned to a variable "x"
x = longest(mylist)

# prints the output
print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a solution to your problem where `longest` can't be found, but a working implementation of your code.

```
def longest(mylist):
    return max(mylist, key=len)

list1 = ["111", "44", "baking", "dot"]
print(longest(list1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in your function.
You're receiving an argument in your function and you're overriding this argument at line 2.
Here what your function needs to look like

```
def longest(mylist):
   mylist = max(mylist, key=len)
   return mylist
```

And then after you're calling your function with your argument

```
mylist = ["111", "44", "baking", "dot"]
mylist = longest(mylist);
print(mylist)
```

Plus in your shell you didn't define your function so the interpreter doesn't know it

Comment: forgot the `return` statement